# Access dataset from another form class

Tags: c#

Loading / storing the 3 floats (ID=1, Loc1=3, Loc2=100) into the public class MInput works fine. However, I like to access / use the same dataset in the Forms2 class, which unfortunately gives me zero values only. What is wrong with the call in Forms2 for textBox1.text and textBox2.text ? Thanks for your ideas.

```
namespace WinForms01
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            MInput testDat = new MInput
            {
               ID = 1F,
               Loc1 = 3F,
               Loc2 = 100F,
            };
        {
    }
}  

namespace WinForms01
{
    public class MInput
    {
       [ColumnName("ID"), LoadColumn(0)]
       public float ID { get; set; }

       [ColumnName("loc1"), LoadColumn(1)]
       public float Loc1 { get; set; }

       [ColumnName("loc2"), LoadColumn(2)]
       public float Loc2 { get; set; }

       [ColumnName("loc3"), LoadColumn(4)]
       public float Loc3 { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WinForms01
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MInput testDat = new MInput();
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(testDat.ID);
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(testDat.Loc1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Form2 to access an object you create elsewhere you have to pass the object to form2. Some instance of class X doesn't just magically get access to an instance of Y just because both different places do a `new Y` and call them the same name, for the same reason that you buying an iPhone and your brother buying an iPhone of the same model and specification, doesn't mean you can read his messages

```
namespace WinForms01
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            MInput testDat = new MInput
            {
               ID = 1F,
               Loc1 = 3F,
               Loc2 = 100F,
            };

            Application.Run(new Form2(testDat));
        }
    }
}  

namespace WinForms01
{
    public class MInput
    {
       [ColumnName("ID"), LoadColumn(0)]
       public float ID { get; set; }

       [ColumnName("loc1"), LoadColumn(1)]
       public float Loc1 { get; set; }

       [ColumnName("loc2"), LoadColumn(2)]
       public float Loc2 { get; set; }

       [ColumnName("loc3"), LoadColumn(4)]
       public float Loc3 { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WinForms01
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private MInput _minput;

        public Form2(MInput minput)
        {
            _minput = minput;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(_minput.ID);
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(_minput.Loc1);
        }
    }
}
```